# Add validation callbacks to ActiveRecord instances in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, refactoring

An ActiveRecord model of ours has a number of validations that unfortunately use the network. For example it uses the Facebook API to validate a given Facebook ID attribute. I want to move these validations out of the model so they are only run in specific contexts and not when being created by Factory Girl in tests. It also needs to be done in an ActiveAdmin compatible way.

My idea is to extract the methods to a module and have that module extend the AR instances as appropriate.

```
module ArtistConnectionValidations
  def self.inject_to(record)
    record.extend self
    record.class_eval do
      before_validation :validate_facebook_name
    end
  end

  def validate_facebook_name
    # Contact Facebook API
  end
end
```

In ActiveAdmin which uses Inherited Resources:

```
controller do  # Executes in controller context
  def resource
    ArtistConnectionValidations.inject_to(Artist.find(params[:id]))
  end
end
```

Unfortunately these validations don't get called as they are added to the instances' singleton class and the `#valid?` method callbacks do not see them. Various other strategies result in it being added to the base class, infecting the entire system. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would work for you. 
But why not creating a subclass?

If I am understanding correctly what you need here, I think it would make the code and usage cleaner.

```
#artist.rb
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
end

#artist_with_validations.rb
class ArtistWithValidations < Artist
  before_validation :validate_facebook_name

  def validate_facebook_name
    # Contact Facebook API
  end
end
```

Then you could use one of the two models depending if you want the user with or without the validations.

Comment: That's a reasonable solution that, semantic issues aside, would probably satisfy most use cases. I think at the time I was hoping for a general solution because I had different types of objects that could have used the same validations.